# How to update store in extJs (it falls with 404 error)?

Tags: extjs

I'm new in ExtJs and i'm stuck with some problems.
This is my model:

```
Ext.define('MyTestApp.model.Product', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

fields: [
    {name: 'id',  type: 'int'},
    {name: 'name',  type: 'string'},
    {name: 'description',  type: 'string'},
    {name: 'price',  type: 'float'},
    {name: 'count',  type: 'int'}
],});
```

This is store:

```
Ext.define('MyTestApp.store.Products', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
alias: 'store.products',
storeId: 'products',

model: 'MyTestApp.model.Product',

data: [
    {id: 1, name: 'Notebook Lenovo', description: 'Ноутбук Lenovo IdeaPad 330-15IKB', price: 100, count: 2},
    {id: 2, name: 'Logitech Keyboard', description: 'Клавиатура Logitech Comfort K280E', price: 50, count: 9},
    {id: 3, name: 'Logitech Mouse', description: 'Мышь Logitech M90', price: 25, count: 0},
    {id: 4, name: 'Gaming mouse pad', description: 'Коврик для мыши A4Tech X7-200MP', price: 150, count: 5},
    {id: 5, name: 'Samsung smartphone', description: 'Смартфон Samsung Galaxy A51 64GB', price: 122, count: 3},
    {id: 6, name: 'Protective glass', description: 'Защитное стекло Samsung InterStep FSC', price: 10, count: 33},
],});
```

I want to add/update some records in the store, but methods such as store.load() or newModelInstance.save() doesn't work. Error in console:
POST http://localhost:1841/MyTestApp.model.Product?_dc=1596285700466 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add new record into store you can use store.add({id:123, name: “some name”...}) method. To update records, something like strore.findRecord() and then update the found record in the store i.e. record.set(fieldName, fieldValue).
To update the store/records data on the server (commit), you must configure proxy for store/record.